# removeChild() on parent will remove its child?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder, flashdevelop

I have a construction as below:

```
parent
   + child
   + child
   + child
   + sub-parent
         + sub-child
         + sub-child
```

For now, I use multiply of "removeChild()", to remove elements from scene one by one. Like this:

```
removeChild(sub-child);
removeChild(sub-child);
removeChild(sub-parent);
//and so on
```

It's okay, but I found out that if I remove a parent all its children will disappear from scene too. (For now I do not know for sure ...)

How do you remove elements from a scene in the correct way ? As I do it now (one by one), or I could remove just a parent and my code will be a little bit shorter. Or is it the same thing?

Comment: Isn't this a question you can easily find an answer to yourself? Simply try it  out and see what happens?

Comment: already did but i do not know it's correct way or not. You see i'm a newbie in as3, so i want to learn it as it should be that's way i'm asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing a display object from the stage will also remove all of that object's children. Think of it as a container that holds those children object. If you remove the container, you also remove the objects inside of it.

However, if you still have references to those children objects, or have event listeners attached to them, they won't be garbage collected (they will stick around in memory executing any code associated with them). So you still need to make sure you clean up everything when you remove the parent object.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the "sub-parent" and its child's will be removed as well from the scene (stage).

Comment: it also would be removed from inherited of stage ?

Comment: what do you mean "inherited of stage"?

Answer (score 0):

The "display list" is a tree structure that looks like this:

[image]

When you add children to a container (`DisplayObjectContainer`), those children will remain as children of that container unless they are specifically removed from it.

When a container or `DisplayObject` is attached to the `stage`, they will render. If the object is a container, all of its descendants (children, children of children and so on) will also render.

If you remove an object from the stage, it and all of its descendants will stop rendering *but their existing parent/child relationships remain in tact*. This means if you add a container with children to the stage again, all of those children will begin to render again as well.

So to more accurately answer your question: removing a container does not actually remove its children. The children will not have a connection to the stage and will not render, *but they are still children of the container*.

With all that said, there is not often a reason that you would need to remove each individual child from a container. So long as the children do not have event listeners attached or are not referenced by the main application in any other way, they will all be eligible for garbage collection when their connection to the stage is severed. Removing the topmost possible container from the stage is perfectly normal.